# Отправка post запроса в controller spring

Tags: javascript, java, mvc

уже день бьюсь над проблемой.Есть js файл который отправляет post запрос

```
    function openCity(evt, cityName) {
    var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
    console.log(cityName);
    var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var url = '/testproject/customer/list/a';
    var params = "monthParam="+cityName;
    http.open('POST', url, true);
    http.setRequestHeader('Content-type', "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8");
    http.send(params);
}
```

запрос с данными успешно принимает контроллер на java

```
    @PostMapping("/list/a")
    public String showFormForAdd(Model theDay,@RequestParam(value="monthParam") String month) {
      System.out.println(month);
      theDay.addAttribute("daysMod",month);
    return "mail";
    }
```

Проблема в том,что данные выводятся в правильно,но я их не могу запихнуть в Model,чтобы в дальнейшем отправить их на jsp страницу.Проверка что присутствуют атрибуты,всегда пусто. Такое происходит только когда post запрос отправляется с js страницы,если отправлять post с jsp  с помощью  button -все работает нормально.В чем может быть причина этого?Может быть я что то упускаю идейно?

```
<c:if test="${not empty daysMod}">
    <h1>sss</h1>
</c:if>
```

UPD всякими пробами понял,что проблема в

```
return "mail";
```

грубо говоря,атрибуты на самом деле добавляются,но jsp не обновляется и поэтому их не видит.Каким способом можно обновить эту же самую страницу?